# Can't login after editing /etc/security/limits.conf

Tags: linux, login, virtual-machine, system-recovery

After edited the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file to set the `nofile` parameter to unlimited, server got hanged . Can't login in via ssh. Tried to take console, issue with console. Will reboot of the VM will solve the login issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Running `ulimit -n unlimited` as superuser on Linux says: `Operation not permitted`.
You need to boot into single user mode and fix your `limits.conf` back and specify some reasonable value, because Linux denies unlimited NOFILE.

Comment: Curious. Will single-user mode ignore `limits.conf`?

Comment: Depends on how init system handles this. If it starts `sulogin` with ulimits from `limits.conf` then I think this is disastrous, but can be easily fixed with rebooting into plain single user with `init=/bin/sh` kernel parameter, which I always use. Then you will not be affected by bad `limits.conf`.